# Rank of a matrix shifted by all one matrix over any field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let $J$ be all one square matrix. Is it true that over any field, for all square matrices $A$, $$|\operatorname{rank}(J\pm A)-\operatorname{rank}(A)|\leq c$$ for some positive constant $c$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Let $A_1, \dots, A_n$ be column vectors, and let $E$ be a vector consisting of all ones. Prove that the rank of the system $(A_1 + E, \dots, A_n + E)$ is at most one more than the rank of the system $(A_1, \dots, A_n)$.

Comment: Yes, it's more or less equivalent. But now it's formulated in terms of the dimension of the space generated by a system of vectors. What can you say about the span of $(A_1 + E, \dots, A_n + E)$ and the span of $(A_1, \dots, A_n, E)$?

Comment: To me it's easier with dimension here.

Comment: You would need to know the answer before saying that it's easier.

Answer (score 0):

answers is $c = 1.$ here is why: your all one matrix $J = aa^T$ where $a$ is the vector with one for all components is of rank one. now use the fact that $rank(A \pm B) \le rank(A) + rank (B),$ with $B = J.$